# Powershell "-gt" comparison returns wrong result

Tags: powershell, comparison

I'm working on a PS program which, among other things, load 2 CSV files with device names, counts the number of devices and then performs an action if the number of devices have increased since last run, and a different action if the number of devices has decreased since last run.

I am completely stumped by what I am seeing:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\(path redacted)>> $Number_of_Current_Devices

20

[DBG]: PS C:\(path redacted)>> $Number_Of_Prior_Devices

5

[DBG]: PS C:(path redacted)>> $Number_of_Current_Devices -gt $Number_Of_Prior_Devices
False

[DBG]: PS C:(path redacted)>>
```

Why on earth does the -gt comparison claim that 20 is NOT larger than 5?

Comment: Try using .GetType() to make sure you're comparing similar types.

Comment: `Import-Csv` imports numbers as strings. You have to cast to a numeric type (e.g., `[Int]`) when comparing for what you are doing to work.

Comment: As @TheIncorrigible1 pointed out a string comparison (char by char) would correctly state that `'2'`is not greater than `'5'`. Should be sufficient to cast the first value to an [int].  `[int]$Number_of_Current_Devices -gt $Number_Of_Prior_Devices`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart `Import-Csv` imports *all* field values as strings :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes that's correct, numbers included.